# Integrate Akka with Spring in Java web application project under Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, akka

I am interested in injecting Actors to beans, while the actors will be created by spring. In addition, I am looking for ways to customize Akka configuration file path.

My project uses Java 7 and spring 3.2.5, akka version is 2.3.7.

I read some documents and guides that instruct to create a bean definition in my spring beans configuration file, as follows:

```
<bean id="system-actor" class="akka.actor.ActorSystem" factory-method="create" destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="MyApp" />
</bean>
```

The system actor created by spring successfully according to default configuration.
Questions:

- I want to initialize the system actor according to **/WEB-INF/application.conf** file, I added the -Dconfig.trace=loads system property in order to debug configuration loading, this is the output:

  Loading config from class loader WebappClassLoader
    context: /MY-APP
    delegate: false
    repositories:
      **/WEB-INF/classes/**
  ----------> Parent Classloader:
  org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@992f73
   but there were no resources called application.conf
  exception loading application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf
  Loading config from class loader WebappClassLoader
    context: /MY-APP
    delegate: false
    repositories:
      **/WEB-INF/classes/**
  ----------> Parent Classloader:
  org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@992f73
   but there were no resources called application.json
  exception loading application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json
  Loading config from class loader WebappClassLoader
    context: /MY-APP
    delegate: false
    repositories:
      **/WEB-INF/classes/**
  ----------> Parent Classloader:
  org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@992f73
   but there were no resources called application.properties
  exception loading application.properties: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties
  Did not find 'application' with any extension (.conf, .json, .properties); but 'application' is allowed to be missing. Exceptions from load attempts should have been logged above.
  Loading config from URL jar:file:/var/work/MY-APP/jakarta-tomcat/webapps/MY-APP/WEB-INF/lib/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.7.jar!/reference.conf from class loader WebappClassLoader
    context: /MY-APP
    delegate: false
    repositories:
      **/WEB-INF/classes/**
  ----------> Parent Classloader:
  org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@992f73
- Is there a way to pass this path to system actor bean?
- There is a way to create actor beans in spring instead of injecting the system actor and using `system.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class), "name");`? Detailed examples will be helpful.
- Many answers to simillar issues point to this article: http://blog.nemccarthy.me/?p=272 but this page is offline, someone knows what's written there?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

You explicitly define where the conf file is stored, by default root classpath dir is scanned, `WEB-INF/classes`

```
-Dconfig.resource=/dev.conf
```

**Q2**

Follow the pattern presented in the [activator-akka-java-spring](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-java-spring), you can use exactly the code from that repository or customize it using your own custom logic. (Sooner or later you'll uderstand why you need to customize it )

You need to keep in mind that extension needs to be initialized with `ctx`

```
SpringExtProvider.get(system).initialize(applicationContext);
```

And then you can wrap it as you want, handling simple actor creation:

```
ActorRef counter = system.actorOf(
      SpringExtProvider.get(system).props("quartz"), "quartz");
```

or even more complex cases with singleton:

```
ActorRef quartzCoordinator = getContext().actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.defaultProps(SpringExtProviderget(getContext().system()).props("quartz"), "quartz",
                PoisonPill.getInstance(), "core"), "coordinator");
```

**Q3**

[Bounty ;)](https://gist.github.com/javajack/7671468)

Comment: I added the configuration load logs, only WEB-INF/classes scanned.

Comment: You're right, by default only root classpath dir is scanned, you can use resource props or extended classpath config